# Add event to every day if the day is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

To better understand my question, take a look at the [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3vqpbv5m/6/).

Basically there are tree kinds of unique items on the calendar that are all day events: **Today**, **Completed**, and **Incomplete** days. I need to figure a way to populate days that don't have anything on them (Today, or Incomplete), in this case they would be populated with "**Completed**". How can I figure out what these days are?

Also any way to limit the calendar to a set months range? For instance Quarter 1 would be Dec 1st to Mar 31st.

```
//Calendar
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Figure out todays date and provide link to enter data
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    // Staff Data Calendar
    $('#calendar-staff').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title',
            },
        businessHours: true, // display business hours
        handleWindowResize: true, // responsive layout
        editable: false,
        events: [
                // red areas where no events can be dropped
                {
                    title: 'No Data',
                    start: '2015-02-03',
                    url: '#',
                    color: '#E64C65'
                },
                {
                    title: 'No Data',
                    start: '2015-02-17',
                    url: '#',
                    color: '#E64C65'
                },
                {
                    // Display Today
                    title: 'Enter Data for Today',
                    url: 'staffing_data_edit.html',
                    color: '#5E9EF3',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d)
                }

            ]

    });
});
```

Comment: Hey I got errors once I pressed "Run"

Comment: jsfiddle not working

Comment: where will you get event data? from a backend? why not simply have the backend send you a list of "events" (ones with "completed" as the title for days that have data, and "incomplete" for those that don't)?  When FullCalendar calls and event URL, it sends a start and end value along with the request.

Comment: It will be on the back end, but for now I am working on a prototype that needs to populated every day that is empty w/ "completed" notice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use and apply a custom check on a event **dayRender** [Click here for reference](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender)

Or you can use event **eventAfterAllRender** which call after the calendar is ready to draw. you can use a loop and check the empty days.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2018-10-25',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: false,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end) {

    },
    dayRender: function(date, cell )
    {
        console.log(date);
        console.log(cell);
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

    },
    eventAfterAllRender: function(view)
    {
        if (view.name == "month") {
            var allEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
            for (var index in allEvents) {
                var event = allEvents[index];

            }
        }
    },
    eventClick: function(event) {

        return false;
    },
    loading: function(bool) {
        //$('#loading').toggle(bool);
    },
    timezone: true,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    eventLimitTex: 'More shifts',
    events: eventsJson
});
```